# Returning Generic type in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, generics

Someone (w69rdy) in Stack Overflow helped me out with a great example to handle DB output, that could potentially be NULL, passed into a function. The problem is I can understand the method as written in C# but I am having a problem understanding how to rewrite the method in VB.NET. The method uses generics and I am lost. Here is the method written in C# ..

```
 public T ParseValue<T>(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader, string column)
 {
     T result = default(T);

     if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal(column)))
         result = (T)reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal(column));

     return result;
 }
```

How is this written in VB.NET? How does the method signature change when returning a generic type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [C# to VB.NET converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) which produces the following results:

```
Public Function ParseValue(Of T)(reader As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader, column As String) As T
    Dim result As T = Nothing

    If Not reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal(column)) Then
        result = DirectCast(reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal(column)), T)
    End If

    Return result
End Function
```

### Additionally:

I would recommend the following resource to help know syntax differences between VB.NET and C#. It has a section on Generics:

[VB.NET and C# Comparison](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html)

Comment: hm seconds before my answer, i suppose i'll remove mine then :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Public Function ParseValue(Of T)(reader As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader, _
                                     column As String) As T
    Dim result As T = Nothing

    If Not reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal(column)) Then
        result = DirectCast(reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal(column)), T)
    End If

    Return result
End Function
```

From [C# to VB.NET converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/).